# If the quadratic equation $x^2+px+q=0$ and $x^2+qx+p=0$ have a common root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, quadratics

> If  quadratic equations $x^2+px+q=0$ and $x^2+qx+p=0$ have a common root, prove that: either $p=q$ or $p+q+1=0$.

My attempt:

Let $\alpha $ be the common root of these equations. Since one root is common, we know:
$$(q-p)(p^2-q^2)=(q-p)^2.$$
How do I get to the proof from here?

Comment: Virtually a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2366474/265466.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can obtain
$$(q-p)(p^2-q^2)=(q-p)^2$$
Since $p^2-q^2=(q-p)(-p-q)$, we have
$$(q-p)^2(-p-q)=(q-p)^2$$

Hence $(q-p)^2(1+p+q)=0$.

Hence $q=p$ or $1+p+q =0$

Answer (score 11):

Let $x$ be the common root.

Thus, $$px+q=qx+p$$ or
$$(x-1)(p-q)=0,$$
which gives $p=q$ or $x=1$ and from this we obtain $p+q+1=0$.

Comment: Where does that $x$ come from?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... $x$ is the common root. Hence, $x^2+px+q=x^2+qx+p$.

Comment: " from here" mean from where?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... It means from $x=1$ we obtain $1^2+p\cdot1+q=0$ or $p+q+1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be the common root.

\begin{align}
   \alpha^2 + p \alpha + q &= 0 \\
   \alpha^2 + q \alpha + p &= 0 \\
\hline
   (p-q)\alpha + (q-p) &= 0 \\
   (p-q)(\alpha-1) &= 0
\end{align}

$\alpha = 1$ or $p=q$.

If $\alpha = 1$, then $\alpha^2 + p \alpha + q = 0$ becomes
$1+p+q = 0$